# Determine that the password has been typed by user or fills automatically?

Tags: c#

I'm developing a desktop application. I use users of windows domain to login to the application. I have a login form with *remember me* check-box.

When user types his/her username and **if** he logged-in before, the password box is filled automatically. If user hasn't logged-in before or has changed his password, he needs to fill password box by himself.

When application fills password box automatically the count of stars in password box is equal with actual password's count and if the password's length isn't much enough, that make it easy to guess actual password.

I know that I can fill password box with fake characters, but when I want to check password I couldn't know the characters which are in password box are fake or typed by user.

What is the **easiest** way to prevent this issue?

Comment: Your suggesting *counting the stars* makes it easy to guess the actual password? You could use some kind of *password strength* indicator when users are selecting a password, this will force them to use a strong password.

Comment: *********** - what is my password?

Comment: The normal way I think should be encrypt password and that's how you will get more stars.

Comment: @christiandev: That is not my problem. I edited the question.

Comment: @Reniuz: I don't know how should explain the problem. I edited the question for more details.

Comment: Can't understand logic of your login. You checking remember me checkbox at first login and another time when you use application you enter your login name and password is filled automatically...but you checked remember me why you need to enter somethig?

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh, I don't think this is an issue - you just need to encrypt a strong password, if you're concerned about whether it was typed by a user, you could use *captcha*?

Comment: @Reniuz, can I guess? **password123**? :)

Comment: @christiandev Nope, correct is Y0u@r3Wr0ng, not so easy? :)

Comment: @Reniuz: I'm using users of windows domain. Maybe user didn't login before, Or maybe user has been changed his password. He should able to edit password field that is filled automatically.

Comment: @Reniuz, damn, that was going to be the next guess!

Comment: Desktop application with a remember me checkbox and automatically fill-in? WinForms or WPF? Is this a standard feature or you do this yourself? Who or what is filling the password textbox and where does it take that value? The problem seems to be before not after.

Comment: @christiandev: That's not the way of answering questions. If question is not clear write comment to clarify that. thank you.

Comment: @christiandev: I tried to clarify my question. Is there any comment to make it better? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string password = //take it from dataBase or the source where you save it.
string addStars = "******";
InitialPassowrd = true;
PasswordTxt.Text = password + addStars;
```

After that when you are taking PasswordTxt.Text for login:

```
string password = PasswordTxt.Text;
string formatPass = password.Substring(0, password.Length - addStars.Length);
```

This is the easiest way which I can think of.

`EDIT`:

For the case when the user change his password and how to check it:

Create one property `InitialPassowrd` or something like that, `false` by default. If the user have save password checked, you set this property to true and add the stars. After that you are adding a event handler on `OnTextChanged="PasswordTxt_TextChanged"` to the PasswordTxt.

**Code behind:**

```
protected void PasswordTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitialPassword = false;
}
```

At the end, when you make the logging:

```
string password = "";
if(InitialPassword)
{
    password = PasswordTxt.Text;
    password = password.Substring(0, password.Length - addStars.Length);
}  
else
{
    password = PasswordTxt.Text;
}
```

Comment: The user can enter his password also. How should I know that?

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh here check it.

Comment: Yes, This is my answer, I don't know the reason of a negative to my question or some joking in comments. thank you mybrithname

Comment: +1 - pretty much what I would have said. Whether you could really call this __secure__ is another question, but the whole idea of wanting to remember users' passwords challenges the definition of security anyway.

Comment: I'm not new in programming , but I've forgotten text-change event for textBox. thank you again.